# Why invoke the same event in the event handler

Tags: c#, .net, events, event-handling

### Background

I am confused about the use case below about event & event handler.

In a constructor, I have the code where:

ProductUpdate is declared as an event -
`public delegate void ProductUpdateEvent(object? sender, EventArgs e);`
and

```
ProductUpdateEvent += (sender, args) => { 
feedConnector.getPrice(Products);
ProductUpdateEvent?.(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

### My understanding

I know that the `ProductUpdateEvent += (sender, args) => { ...}` part means:

- the RHS lamba expression is added to the invocation list of the LHS ProductUpdateEvent
- so whenever LHS ProductUpdateEvent happens, the RHS lamba expression will be triggered

`ProductUpdateEvent?.(this, EventArgs.Empty)` means if there is event handler for the ProductUpdateEvent, trigger the event (which means the actions in invocation list will be triggered)

- please correct me if I am wrong in my understanding above

### What I don't understand

- Why are we raising the event in the event handler? Wouldn't this cause a recursive call? (I guess it won't be a recursive call because it's in a production code base already, but I don't understand why) Maybe in this context it has different meaning?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yes it looks to be recursive. What happened when you debugged it?

Comment: Looks recursive to me. Can you please share more code?